# Android: Failing to receive BottomSheetDialog state change callbacks

Tags: android, performance, callback, bottom-sheet

I have implemented `BottomSheetDialog` like this:

```
addLinkSheet = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
addLinkSheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_quickadd_wagrouplink, null);
addLinkSheet.setContentView(addLinkSheetView);
addLinkSheet.show();
```

I am trying to listen to the state changes of Bottom sheet (Expanded/Collapsed/Hidden) using this code:

```
BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View)addLinkSheetView.getParent());
    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            Toast.makeText(QuickAddWaGroup.this, "State changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
```

My BottomSheet is showing properly, but I am never seeing the `Toast` of state being changed. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you eventually figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to wrap the Callback inside the `OnShowListener` of the BottomSheetDialog and it should work:

```
bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
View contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_content_view, null);
bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(contentView);
bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);
bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View)contentView.getParent());
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "State Expanded");
                    // ... do whatever is required on 'expanded'
                } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    if (Math.abs(slideOffset) > 0) {
                        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }
});

// Get your contentView children set here...
bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

To close the bottomSheetdialog; you will need:

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Which will trigger the onStateChanged event again and dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I was initally trying to override `onCreateView` method in the Fragment to setup layout but Bottom Sheet state changes were not being notified. I was able to listen for state changes only after I override the `setupDialog` method in my BottomSheetDialogFragment instead of `onCreateView`. Here is the sample code

```
public class AddMetricFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback bottomSheetCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        // React to state change
            Log.d("logtag", "Bottom Sheet State " + newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        // React to dragging events

    }
};

@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);

    contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
    if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback);
    }
}
```

}